# How to call/use 1 controller of $scope in another controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is that how to call 1 controller $scope to another controller in Angular JS.
Bascially The structure is that, I have two controller one is AddController and the other one is ViewController. Basically I want the form with fields of AddController in ViewController.  $rootScope.name = data.name, email and phone is not showing the data on the form fields once I click on Edit.

What I've already tried.

In HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AddController">
    <legend>Add Students</legend>
    <form class="well">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email" />
      <label>Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="phone" />
      <br/>

      <div ng-if="isUpdate">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-model="id" />
      </div>

      <div ng-show="addData">
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveStudent()" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
      <div ng-show="!addData">
        <input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="updateStudent()" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ViewController">
    <legend>View Students</legend>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
          <td>{{ $index; }}</td>
          <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ student.email }}</td>
          <td>{{ student.phone }}</td>
          <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="edit($index)">Edit</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="delete($index)">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

In JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('StudentsData', function($rootScope){
    var s;
    var students = [
        {name: 'Tariq Ali', email: 'chk.webstar@gmail.com', phone: '58757'},
        {name: 'Faizan Ali', email: 'kdjy.webstar@gmail.com', phone: '24545'}
    ];

    this.list = function(){
        return students;
    }

    this.single = function(id){
        for(s=0; s<=students.length; s++){
            if(s == id){
                return students[s];
            }
        }
    }

    this.insert = function(data){
        students.push(data);
    }

    this.update = function(updatedData, id){
        for(s=0; s<=students.length; s++){
            if(s == id){
                students[s] = updatedData;
            }
        }
    }

    this.delete = function(id){
        students.splice(id, 1);
    }

    this.name = function(){

    }


});

app.controller('AddController', function($scope, StudentsData, $rootScope){

    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);

    $rootScope.addData = true;
    $scope.saveStudent = function(){
        StudentsData.insert({name: $scope.name, email: $scope.email, phone: $scope.phone});

        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.email = '';
        $scope.phone = '';
    }

    $scope.updateStudent = function(){
        var updatedData = {name: $scope.name, email: $scope.email, phone: $scope.phone};
        StudentsData.update(updatedData, $scope.id);

        /*$scope.name = '';
        $scope.email = '';
        $scope.phone = '';
        $rootScope.addData = true;*/
    }


});

app.controller('ViewController', function($scope, StudentsData, $rootScope){

    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) {console.log(mass)});

    $scope.students = StudentsData.list();

    $scope.delete = function(id){
        StudentsData.delete(id);
    }

    $scope.edit = function(id){
        var data = StudentsData.single(id);

        $rootScope.name = data.name;
        $rootScope.email = data.email;
        $rootScope.phone = data.phone;
        $rootScope.addData = false;
        $rootScope.isUpdate = true;
        $rootScope.id = id;
        //console.log($rootScope.addData);

        //StudentsData.update(id);
    }
});
```

Here is my fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/npm5u5h0/
For first time if you click on edit its working fine but if you add a new student and after edit the newly created student the textfields are not showing the data.

Comment: why don't you put them in one controller?

Comment: why are you using `$rootScope` for the fields in ViewCtrl and not `$scope`?

Comment: @charlietfl because $rootScope is sometimes working as I want. but $scope isn't working even in a single time

Comment: somethings wrong then. Shouldn't have to do it that way. Likely the fact that you aren't using objects rather primitives

Comment: @charlietfl, you can check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/npm5u5h0/ For first time if you click on edit its working fine but if you add a new student and after edit the newly created student the textfields are not showing the data.

Comment: you really need to learn how to use objects in angular. `ng-model` should always have a dot in it.

Comment: @charlietfl, I've used the dot with ng-model, Still the same issue.. Any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not have two controllers that both call the same service? They you could put the information in the service and have them both reference that.

```
angular.module('mycontrollers').controller('controllername', ['myService', function (myService) {
    $scope.email = myService.getEmail;
}]);

angular.module('mycontrollers').controller('controllername2', ['myService', function (myService) {
    $scope.email = myService.getEmail;
}]);

angular.module('myservices').service('myService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var self = this;
    self.getEmail = function () {
       ...
       return $rootScope.email;
    };
    self.setEmail = function (email) {
        $rootScope.email = email;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: not working. here is my fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/npm5u5h0/
For first time if you click on edit its working fine but if you add a new student and after edit the newly created student the textfields are not showing the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could name the addContoller div with an ID such as "addController"

Then from within your viewController, you could grab the other scope with

var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#addController'));
  var myScope = angular.element(myEl).scope();

and then $scope.name = myScope.name

Comment: Note: There is certainly a cleaner way to do this with injection, but I am answering the question directly.

Comment: The Controller should never have any code that deals with the DOM, regardless if its querying DOM elements or manipulating them. Tom's answer is the way to go with the problem, as for your solution it sways away against AngularJS principles.

Comment: Fair enough. But that wasn't the question.

"Basically I want the form with fields of AddController in ViewController."

Comment: You might want to read the [Developer's Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller), make sure to read the "Do not use controllers to" list. Specifically, the first and fourth item on the list.

Comment: Here is my fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/npm5u5h0/
For first time if you click on edit its working fine but if you add a new student and after edit the newly created student the textfields are not showing the data.